# Documentation - Adding requests for deleting topics

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, documentation

As of now, users can request improvement to existing topics, and request creation of new ones.

I believe there should also be the option to remove topics that have been added due to review oversight and are better off being deleted.

For example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/9473/competitive-programming-with-python#t=201706141953043531127) topic in python is blatantly opinionated and off-topic, and would offer little to no value for any reader. From what I could see, there is nothing such as a recommendation for deletion.

How have cases such as this been handled? Should the topic be flagged? That seems a little excessive, considering it does not require moderator invention, just a vote to close/delete.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just delete it. Your change will be reviewed like any other.

Comment: Huh. That's weird. I thought I had deleted them previously. Guess you'd have to flag for moderator attention, since it appears we mortals can't delete them.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Scratch that, figured it out. If you delete the introduction, the whole thing gets deleted.